How do you say derogatorily "you should be happy about what I did to you"?

In my native language, you can say “I did something because I think highly of you” or “my doing something is respect for you” (literal translations) as a retort or put-down when somebody criticizes what you did to him/her. For example, when you (A) pat somebody (B) on the back and he says “don’t touch me”, you can say that. When I translated it literally it doesn’t seem to be a put-down in English. A paraphrase can be “you should be honored that I did x.” In my native language, it means because I’m superior to you, even if you think I did something wrong to you, you should be honored and happy that I deigned to do that to you. I’d like to know how to say that idiomatically in English. Thank you.

If there's no equivalent phrases in English. Let's think outside the box. What would you say as a retort to B after his saying "don't touch me"? "Don't get your panties in a wad"? Thank you.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Combining 2 idioms : Whether you like it or not, I did it for your own good.

I’m voting not to help on either putting people down when they object to our actions, or defending an assault because "you should be happy about what I did to you."

We have an idiom that might work:

to kiss the ground someone walks on

If someone says I kiss the ground you walk on, it means they greatly admire or respect you.
If someone says You should kiss the ground I walk on, it means they think you owe them admiration and respect.
Reference:

kiss the ground someone walks on

(admiration) admire someone greatly She would kiss the ground he walks on, she’s so in love.

(respect) show extreme respect They kiss the ground their leader walks on, following every command.


Source: Reverso

See also: kiss the ground (to prostrate oneself on the ground in token of homage) and homage (acknowledgement of superiority in respect of rank, worth, beauty, or some other quality; reverence, dutiful respect, or honour shown to someone or something; an instance or expression of this). Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)

You cannot tell someone to feel honored that you have condescended to involve yourself in their piddling life—not if you want them to actually feel honored. But if the intention is to belittle them, to humiliate them and "put them in their place", there is a set phrase that has a derogatory, dismissive sense:

... the likes of you.

and another phrase

the time of day

which is often employed dismissively

I wouldn't give him the time of day.

You wouldn't even tell that person what time it was if they should ask.
You could combine those phrases in a snide remark:

You should feel proud I've given the likes of you the time of day.


Is the word “honored” wrong. Does it only mean “respected”? Can it mean “delighted”? If it can mean “delighted”, then the logic of the sentence’s not wrong.

honored doesn't have connotations of "delighted" although someone who is honored can take pleasure in being respected. Feeling honored is a "good" feeling. As for the logic of your question, you use the word "derogatorily" in the title and mention that the translation did not seem like the "put-down" you wanted it to be. Possibly a cultural blind-spot for me, but I don't see how any person can be expected to find delight in being reminded that they are someone's social inferior. "Ah, I should have felt honored, not patronized. I can now die a happy man."


Social classes really exist. A is not telling B that he should be honored because he’s inferior, but because A condescends to involve himself in B’s piddling life. (I like what you wrote.) There’re thousands upon thousands of Bs. A ignores most of them, but did something to B. Of course, the expression’s a put-down, so A doesn’t have to be actually superior to B. A just says that to anger B. 2. Some people do respect the strong. That’s why some conquered people praise their conquerors.


I use “honored” because I don’t know what else to use in that sentence. I hear people say “I’m honored” a lot when other people do something to them. So what exactly does “honored” mean?

I don't believe there's an equivalent phrase in English. Some close phrases might be

"Consider yourself lucky."
This is a dismissive retort that implies the person should feel fortunate for whatever the speaker has done.

"You're welcome, by the way."
This is a sarcastic phrase that flips the script on the receiver to imply that they're ungrateful.



I'd say "Think yourself lucky" (or I would if I was much less polite), but it's the same idea.

The expression "Don't bite the hand that feeds you" might be appropriate.
Cambridge defines "to bite the hand that feeds you" as "to act badly toward the person who is helping or has helped you."

In my question, A doesn't help B. A just does something to B that B doesn't like.
